# SharePoint Online Communication site editing session inactivity

Tags: sharepoint-online, communication-site

We have a SharePoint Online communication site with the SitePages library. When any page is opened for Edit and kept on edit mode for about 5 minutes, we get the inactivity message as below:

> Your Editing session has ended due to inactivity. Your changes have
> been saved in the latest draft version of this page.

[image]

However, the client is unhappy about this as the message appears after 5 minutes of inactivity which is too early.
So, Is there a way to change the inactivity session time-out to more than 5 minutes? and what is the default value of the inactivity session timeout?

However, I have tested this on another tenant, where I do not receive this session inactivity upon editing the page for about 15-30 minutes, I am confused here on the behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is OOTB behavior. I am able to reproduce the issue on my tenant.

As mentioned in the [Modern Page Life Cycle](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/management-and-lifecycle-of-a-sharepoint-modern-page-3410a04c-3ca4-4a4c-b867-33ab5c8bdcf3#bkmk_pagelifcyle)

> An exception is that if the page has no activity for 5 minutes, the
> editing session will time out and the page will be "unlocked."

I do not find any configuration to update this timeout duration.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Litt Spector. By design, the timeout of inactive editing session is 5 minutes. Changing the timeout of inactive editing session is not available. I suggest you go to [Microsoft Q&A](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/content/idea/post.html) post your suggestions to let users customize the timeout of inactive editing session.